# How to get an array with column names of a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, orm

I need an array with the column names of a table

Any ideas how I can do this with rails 3.0.0rc?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Suppose you have a Post model:

```
Post.column_names
# or
Post.columns.map { |column| column.name }
```

It will return an array with column names of the table 'posts'.

Comment: ...or just use `Post.column_names`

Answer (score 37):

### [ActiveRecord::Base#column_names](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/column_names/class)

create a model:

```
$ rails g model Post title:string body:string
```

verify **app/models/post.rb**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

from your terminal:

```
$ rake db:migrate
$ rails c
> Post.column_names
```

should produce:

```
=> ["id", "title", "body", "created_at", "updated_at"]
```

*credit to [@dombesz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/174257/dombesz)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479551/how-to-get-an-array-with-column-names-of-a-table#comment-8938069) in [Andrea Pavoni](https://stackoverflow.com/users/219589/andrea-pavoni)'s answer*

Answer (score 20):

**For ActiveRecord:**

```
Model.column_names
```

---

**For Mongoid:**

```
Model.attribute_names
```

---

**Output:**

```
=> ["id", "title", "body", "created_at", "updated_at"]
```

*Note: It'll be `_id` instead of `id` for Mongoid*

Comment: Is this not the best answer? Cuts right to the chase.