# Pulling attribute names from associated child model to parent model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class User
  has_many :addresses

  def csv_header
    self.addresses.attribute_names
  end

  def csv_values
    self.addresses.all do |addr|
      addr.attributes.values
    end
  end
end

class Address
  belongs_to :user
end
```

*i am trying to pull the attribute names of the address model to user model,but this method isn't working so can anyone help *

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get an array with column names of a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479551/how-to-get-an-array-with-column-names-of-a-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not much needed here - I think you just need to [map](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/map) the `addresses` in `csv_values`.

```
class User
  has_many :addresses

  def csv_header
    addresses.attribute_names
  end

  def csv_values
    addresses.map do |addr|
      addr.attributes.values
    end
  end
 end

class Address
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Does that fix this for you?

I'd be tempted to shift things around a little for clarity in the code and make use of `delegate`:

```
class user
  ...
  delegate :attribute_names, to: :addresses, prefix: true, allow_nil: true
  ...
end

class Address
  ...
  def self.mapped_values
    all.map { |addr| addr.attributes.values }
  end
  ...
end
```

Then you can just call `user.addresses_attribute_names` and `user.addresses.mapped_values`.

You can also just call `Address.column_names` to get the header array, if it will always stay consistent, as is likely to be the case.

Hope that helps!

---

**Update based on comment:**

To achieve the same for users, you can call the following:

Either call `User.column_names` or `user.attribute_names` to get the headers (on the class for the former, and an instance for the latter).

If you also need the users' mapped values, you can copy across the `self.mapped_values` method from the address model and use that. It's a little duplication, but for a pair of methods like this I wouldn't be inclined to separate these into a separate module.

Final tip - if you're calling the `address` methods from a collection of users (i.e. `User.all`) make sure you adjust it to [include](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes) the addresses to avoid hitting your database in an inefficient way (`User.includes(:addresses)...`).

Comment: this is very helpful, could one also include attributes for the user model in conjunction with the address attributes.

Comment: Morning @MykBKibz - have updated my answer to include this :)